# Power BI - Show TOP n months based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, selectedvalue

I have following issue:
dimDate table - columns like Date, Year, Year-Month, ...
factSales table - related to dimDate via Date column

In factSales I'm doing e.g.: SUM(factSales[Sales]). Showing this measure in graph, where on the x axis I have Year-Month from dimDate & whole page is filtered by dimDate[Year-Month] slicer.

What I want to achive is that when I choose e.g. 2021-03 in the slicer, I'll get chart showing 2021-03 as last month + previous n months (based on selection).

Don't you have experience how to achive that?

[image: Details]

Thanks

Comment: you can generate your start and end date using DAX based on selected month in the slicer. then use those start and end date in measure to calculate values for this and previous month.

Comment: thx. Yeah, this I did - eomonth for last day in month based on selected month, then starting date definition, then calculate(measure, filter(table,date>=starting, date<=end + also defined ALL to ignore selected value from slicer, but still getting only one concrete selected month on graph

Comment: inside CALCULATE, try with DATESBEWEET function to filter data for start and end date.

Comment: measure itself is giving correct number, but months on x axis (from dim_date) are not changing, always showing just selectedvalue

Comment: Can you show some sample data and your current output?

Comment: Hi, added more info into starting question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve last n months based on selected month on slicer, I just had to add month column on x axis of chart from another table as dim_Date. So I just had to create month column in dim_Sales.